# How to make service continues to work after the app is restarted

Tags: java, android

I have a service works by pressing a button.
There's a counter that works every second inside it.
I tested it and it's working. 
It also works after the application is shut down.
The problem after the application is closed 
Then I'm doing a run 
test the service it doesn't work.
How do I make it works after i do run from inside Android studio ?

//MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(!isMyServiceRunning(SensorService.class)){
            Log.i("isServiceRunning","Not");
        }else {
            Log.i("isServiceRunning","Don");
        }
    }

    public void Test(View view){
        startService(new Intent(this, SensorService.class));
    }

    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}



/// Service 

public class SensorService extends Service {

    public int counter=0;

    public SensorService() {
        super();
        Log.i("HERE", "here I am!");
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        startTimer();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("EXIT", "ondestroy!");
      //  Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver.class);
        stoptimertask();
    }

    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask timerTask;
    long oldTime=0;
    public void startTimer() {
        //set a new Timer
        Log.i("startTimer", "Don");
        timer = new Timer();
        //initialize the TimerTask's job
        initializeTimerTask();
        //schedule the timer, to wake up every 1 second
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000); //
    }

    /**
     * it sets the timer to print the counter every x seconds
     */
    public void initializeTimerTask() {
        Log.i("initializeTimerTask", "Don");
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                Log.i("in_timer", "in timer ++++  "+ (counter++));
            }
        };
    }

     /**
     * not needed
     */

    public void stoptimertask() {
        //stop the timer, if it's not already null
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use "Run" from Android Studio (regardless if it's tests or the app) the service will always stop first since the whole application will always stop first. The service will not stop if you start the App manually from the device.

There is no way around this and is actually a good feature. It ensures that the App is always started cleanly on every run. If you want to share the reason of why you want to do this, there might be an alternate way of solving your problem.